# Dynamic Programming code to return the shortest way to sum numbers from an array to a target integer does not return the correct answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I am following a yt video on Dynamic Programming. The problem statement is: "Given an array nums, find the shortest combination of numbers (repetition allowed) from it that sums upto a given target sum"

This is the code:

```
def bestSum(t: int, nums: list, memo = {}):
    if t in memo:
        return memo[t]
    
    #base cases
    if t == 0:
        return []
    if t < 0:
        return None
    
    shortestSum = None

    #Non-base case shenanigans
    for i in nums:
        rem = t - i
        res = bestSum(rem, nums, memo)

        if res != None:
            res.append(i)
            if shortestSum == None or len(res) < len(shortestSum):
                shortestSum = res
    
    memo[t] = shortestSum
    return shortestSum
    
print(bestSum(100, [1,2,5,25]))
```

The answer should be [25, 25, 25, 25] but I am getting a completely different array that sums to >100 as the output. Can someone tell me what is wrong in this code?